# I got a warning message from App store connect - iOS app has to be build with iOS 16.1 SDK or later after April 2023

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, codenameone

iOS app must be built with iOS 16.1 SDK or later for acceptance by App store connect after April 2023.

> WARNING ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 15.4 SDK. Starting April 2023, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 16.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 14.1 or later."

Can the cn1 build server upgrade its iOS SDK?

Comment: Please notice the tag. This question is for codenameone.

Comment: This warning message is not only related to `codenameone`, that's why I changed the tag.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I tried to submit my app on app-connect and here is what I did to fix the problem:

1. Download `Xcode 14.2` from https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode
2. Extract `Xcode 14.2.app` from the download file `Xcode_14.2.xip` and copy it to my `applications`
3. Open my project from the new `Xcode 14.2` for build and submit my app on app-connect.

and Voila!

---

For more details on Xcode 14.1 and App Store, visit: https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

Comment: For `Xcode 14.3` you will need `macOS 13.3.x` installed. if you don't have this version of macOS, update or install Xcode 14.2 or 14.1.

Comment: Can this work on a 2016 Macbook?

Comment: Sure, recently my friend installed ```Xcode 14.2``` on macOS 2015, just make sure you have at least ```macOS Monterey``` installed on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

We are [aware of this issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/11y7nua/ios_api_level/). We plan to update the servers to use the latest xcode during the first week of April at the latest.

Comment: I send cn1's iOS AppStore build to the App store but got a warning on Transporter. "Could not find a MudhornDescriberCapabilities service provider"

Comment: This seems to be a new thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75967061/whats-the-mudhorndescribercapabilities-service-in-the-new-ios-for-ios16

Not sure where it's coming from.

Comment: related but now with mudhorndescribercapabilities ->  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75967061/whats-the-mudhorndescribercapabilities-service-in-the-new-ios-for-ios16