# What's the MudhornDescriberCapabilities Service in the new IOS for IOS16?

Tags: xcode, testflight, itms90725

When I was uploading a new release on TestFlight a message appeared:

[image]

What actually it means?

Comment: Did this happen on April 1?

Comment: No, 2 days ago, on 2023-04-09. Maybe some mistaken message from Apple Side, who knows.

Comment: Really seems like a joke

Comment: Got the same error message

Comment: Same error today, no idea what's causing it.

Comment: same happening here

Comment: Same here, for a Mac Store app that I've been regularly updating. Is anyone from Apple reading this? Someone knows...[Edit: the App Store seems to have accepted the upload regardless, so maybe the Mudhorns (Mudhens?) are not really interfering.]

Comment: Same warning message happening for me too. iOS app on 2023-04-14.

Comment: I am also getting the mudhorn warning (last tried on 2023-04-17), I am trying to upload the build using Transporter.

Comment: Why are y'all focussing on the first warning so much? I'd rather be concerned with the 2nd one, which tells you that starting in a few days, you'll not be able to submit apps using your current setup anymore. Look for ways to update to at least Xcode 14.1 to continue to be able to upload apps.

Comment: @Gereon I have already updated the Xcode to the latest released version i.e. v14.3
Still getting this, so worried